# How to display tray icon for Windows Defender in Windows Server 2019 (1809)?

Tags: windows-registry, icons, notification-area, windows-defender, windows-server-2019

I'm looking for a way to display a tray icon for running Windows Defender under Windows Server 2019 in a similar way that non-server version is showing it.

What I checked:

- The Feature "Windows Defender Antivirus" is activated and running
- I searched for "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MSASCuiL.exe" which seems to be responsible for the tray icon on non-server version of Windows 10 as per [this](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-show-or-hide-windows-defender-tray-icon-in-windows-10/), but there is only MpCmdRun.exe

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To activate the Windows Defender notification icon for all users:

#### 1. Open Local Group Policy Editor (**Start / Run / "gpedit"**)

#### 2. Go to :

> Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows
> Components / Windows Security / Systray / **Hide Windows Security Systray**

#### 3. Set to Disabled

#### 4. Click OK & Reboot the machine

Comment: Thank you Alex, this worked :)

To me surprise to be honest, since it was set to not configured which should be the same as disabled according to the description.